# supervisord with php received SIGCLD indicating a child quit

Tags: gearman, supervisord

Trying to start supervisor and get a bunch of these errors

```
2011-06-08 23:35:45,833 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2011-06-08 23:35:45,851 INFO supervisord started with pid 19617
2011-06-08 23:35:45,852 INFO spawned: 'gearman-worker' with pid 19620
2011-06-08 23:35:45,899 INFO exited: gearman-worker (exit status 1; not expected)
2011-06-08 23:35:45,900 INFO received SIGCLD indicating a child quit
2011-06-08 23:35:46,902 INFO spawned: 'gearman-worker' with pid 19621
2011-06-08 23:35:46,943 INFO exited: gearman-worker (exit status 1; not expected)
2011-06-08 23:35:46,944 INFO received SIGCLD indicating a child quit
2011-06-08 23:35:48,945 INFO spawned: 'gearman-worker' with pid 19622
2011-06-08 23:35:48,996 INFO exited: gearman-worker (exit status 1; not expected)
2011-06-08 23:35:48,996 INFO received SIGCLD indicating a child quit
2011-06-08 23:35:51,998 INFO spawned: 'gearman-worker' with pid 19623
2011-06-08 23:35:52,041 INFO exited: gearman-worker (exit status 1; not expected)
2011-06-08 23:35:52,041 INFO received SIGCLD indicating a child quit
2011-06-08 23:35:53,041 INFO gave up: gearman-worker entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
2011-06-08 23:35:57,671 CRIT received SIGINT indicating exit request
```

My supervisord conf:

```
[supervisord]

[program:gearman-worker]
user=nobody
command=/usr/bin/php -e index.php -a 'qworker'
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
numprocs=10
directory=/home/test/public_html/
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: This may be related to your case [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28937722/supervisord-exit-status-1-not-expected-running-php-script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28937722/supervisord-exit-status-1-not-expected-running-php-script)

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP program is exiting which probably has nothing to do with supervisord.

1. Try running the worker on the command line first and see if that works
2. Check the stderr log that supervisord creates for this process to look for clues

Answer (score 0):

Is /home/test/public_html/ already created?

su - nobody and run the script to test if it works as nobody

Comment: `This account is currently not available.` - instead try: `su -s /bin/bash nobody`

Answer (score 0):

Check with your apache and mysql server of your local if it is running then stop it.

```
1.sudo service apache2 stop
2.sudo service mysql stop
```

and try now It's woking on Ubuntu If you have windows system with XAMPP simply stop the services from XAMPP control panel.