# Why are my Laravel Queue Jobs failing after 60 seconds?

Tags: php, laravel, queue

**The Situation**

I'm using Laravel Queues to process large numbers of media files, an individual job is expected to take minutes (lets just say up to an hour).

I am using Supervisor to run my queue, and I am running 20 processes at a time.  My supervisor config file looks like this:

```
[program:duplitron-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/duplitron/artisan queue:listen database --timeout=0 --memory=500 --tries=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=duplitron
numprocs=20
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/duplitron/storage/logs/duplitron-worker.log
```

There are a few oddities that I don't know how to explain or correct:

1. My jobs fairly consistently fail after running for 60 to 65 seconds.
2. After being marked as failed the job *continues to run* even after being marked as failed.  Eventually they do end up resolving successfully.
3. When I [run the failed task in isolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34485265/how-can-i-learn-more-about-why-my-laravel-queued-job-failed) to find the cause of the issue it succeeds just fine.

I strongly believe this is a timeout issue; however, I was under the impression that `--timeout=0` would result in an unlimited timeout.

**The Question**

How can I prevent this temporary "failure" job state?  Are there other places where a queue timeout might be invoked that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Check the `max_execution_time` your php.ini

How much does it says? If it's 60 secs, there's your problem. try increasing the timeout.

Comment: Great thought @WillyPt -- wouldn't the php.ini settings terminate the entire script, though?  It continues to resolve.  (FWIW `max_execution_time` was set to 30s, I'll explore and experiment along those lines).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It turns out that in addition to timeout there is an `expire` setting defined in `config/queue.php`

```
    'database' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'jobs',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
```

Changing that to a higher value did the trick.

---

**UPDATE:** This parameter is now called `retry_after`

```
    'database' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'jobs',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'retry_after' => 60,
    ],
```

Comment: Thank you sir, this helps me solve my problem. But as pointed out by David's answer, "expire" now called "retry_after"

Comment: I have implemented the queue for importing huge CSV, I will not go to the server every time to check the progress PHP artisan queue:work how to handle this case? @slifty?

Answer (score 13):

Important note: "expire" is now called "retry_after" (Laravel 5.4)

Answer (score 6):

This will work

```
php artisan queue:listen --timeout=1200
```

Adjust the time based on your need

Comment: I have implemented the queue for importing huge CSV, I will not go to the server every time to check the progress PHP artisan queue:work how to handle this case? @Munna Khan

Comment: You can set a scheduler to keep the queue worker alive. Another way to configure supervisor on your server.

Comment: Yes, perfect thanks for the help!  Supervisor should keep queue alive running.

Comment: NOTE: If this is null (aka not set) there will not be a timeout for the QUEUE WORKER. The JOB timeout defaults to 60 seconds. That can be changed in the job which is not what the answer does. This answer looks to be conflating the two timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am using `Symfony\Component\Process\Process`. I have to set timeout as following as well.

```
$process = new Process([...]);
$process->setTimeout(null);
```