# Running 'docker exec' in systemd service (code=exited, status=216/GROUP)

Tags: docker, systemd

I'm trying to configure `docker exec` with systemd service, but it always fail.

- The command is working fine when executed directly in the terminal (ssh).

Q: Is that possible to run that way or I need to use inside a bash script (.sh)?

---

/etc/systemd/system/laravel.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Laravel Queue
After=docker.service
Requires=docker.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart="/usr/bin/docker exec -it my_docker /usr/bin/php artisan queue:work --env=production --tries 2 --timeout 60"
User=ubuntu
Group=ubuntu
KillMode=process
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

sudo service vetspay status

```
jan 05 03:04:39 legolas systemd[1]: Started Laravel Queue.
jan 05 03:04:39 legolas systemd[1]: laravel.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=216/GROUP
jan 05 03:04:39 legolas systemd[1]: laravel.service: Unit entered failed state.
jan 05 03:04:39 legolas systemd[1]: laravel.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the command inside a script and got the error: `the input device is not a TTY`

Basically I cannot use the command with `-t` because those are non interactive. Removing it now it's working properly!

---

Where I found the answer:

[the input device is not a TTY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099116/the-input-device-is-not-a-tty)

Comment: There are more corner cases involved in running docker from systemd than this answer addresses. Consider using [`systemd-docker`](https://github.com/ibuildthecloud/systemd-docker) -- this provides SD_NOTIFY socket integration, bridges the differences in cgroup conventions, handles propagating logs through, and otherwise resolves the issue more comprehensively.

Answer (score 1):

The error (the input device is not...) is caused by : **-it** in this line `ExecStart="/usr/bin/docker exec -it my_docker /usr/bin/php artisan queue:work --env=production --tries 2 --timeout 60"
User=ubuntu` , remove it, it is not necessary when docker exec is in bash file