# What does mean "stdin is not a tty" and what can cause it related to only R scripts?

Tags: r, cygwin

I have been running R scripts from the cywing terminal (i'm on my local windows, no remote sessions), it had worked normaly, until now, out of the blue, I get:

> stdin is not a tty

whenever I try running R scrips as 'Rscript script_name.r'.

I even tried something simple: an R hello world. I can run it OK in the RStudio ide, either using the run button or using the Rscript command in the terminal tab. Just not in the cygwin terminal.

However, in the cygwin terminal I can still run my other C and python scripts without any issues.  So, the issue may be R related, somehow? It had been working normaly until this started happening out of the blue. I really have no clue...

Comment: Cygwin built R or Windows one ? The Windows one is probably confused by the Cygwin pseudo tty enviroment tipical of Unix like enviroment.

Comment: It's basically the same thing as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48623005/docker-error-the-input-device-is-not-a-tty-if-you-are-using-mintty-try-prefi) and others like it, but applied to R instead of Docker.  Same difference though.  Windows applications not built for Cygwin can't recognize when they're running in a Cygwin TTY.  So you need to prefix your calls to them using the `winpty` program.  It adapts native Windows programs to the Cygwin TTY.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [docker error : the input device is not a TTY. If you are using mintty, try prefixing the command with 'winpty'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48623005/docker-error-the-input-device-is-not-a-tty-if-you-are-using-mintty-try-prefi)