# Error running interactive Docker on git-bash (prefixing winpty doesn't help)

Tags: docker, git-bash

I'm new to Docker.

I have a simple DockerFile:

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04

CMD echo "Test"
```

I built the image using the docker build command (docker build -t dt_test .).
All that I want to do is run the docker image interactively on Git bash. The path in git has been set up to include the docker toolbox.

When I run the interactive docker run command: "docker run -it dt_test"
it gives me an ERROR:

```
the input device is not a TTY. If you are using mintty, try prefixing the command with 'winpty'
```

So I've tried prefixing the run command with winpty, and it executes the command but doesn't show me the interactive shell. When I type something, I cant see any of the commands that I'm typing into the terminal. I have to then type "reset" and then it sets the terminal back to normal. So I guess the winpty command isn't working

Questions:

1. Is there something wrong with the "winpty docker run -it dt_test" command and why doesn't it work?
2. How can I fix this issue to make my file run interactively?

FYI: When I run the docker file non interactively it seems to work fine. shows "Test" in the terminal according to the Dockerfile.

Comment: Can you try `docker run -i dt_test`? (without the `-t`)

Comment: As another solution, you can use [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/install.html) instead of `git-bash`. `git-bash` is a limited toolset and is less suitable for a wide range of *nix-like utilities. You can also take advantage of Docker for Window's PowerShell support to run similar commands without any trouble.

Comment: @RobertSeaman The command without the -t runs, but it doesn't give me an interactive shell. It just runs the dockerfile as is (same as docker run dt_test).

Comment: I don't know what your ENTRYPOINT is, but why don't you run it with `--entrypoint bash`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to be the same as [the input device is not a TTY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099116/the-input-device-is-not-a-tty).

Try without the `-t`:

```
docker run -i dt_test
```

And to run it with a different entrypoint (like bash):

```
docker run -i --entrypoint bash dt_test
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you!! Not sure how --entrypoint bash affected this, but I was using the default entry point /bin/sh -c