# winpty consumes git bash shell

Tags: git-bash, tty, docker-toolbox

I have Windows 10. I can't enable Hyper V, so I'm using Docker Toolbox. My terminal of choice is git bash, which is a Msys2 terminal. Normally, everything works fine, except when I need an interactive terminal. For instance,

```
docker login artifactory.mycompany.com
```

gives:

```
Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device
```

When I try instead

```
winpty docker login artifactory.mycompany.com
```

nothing happens, but my console input and output is completely consumed (nothing is displayed when I type). The only way I can get out of it is by typing `exit` or restarting `git bash`, which is obviously not useful.

How do I get winpty to work correctly with git bash?
Or is there another way to use interactive docker commands within git bash?

Comment: This seems related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099116/the-input-device-is-not-a-tty, but is almost the opposite issue.