# Run docker command in php

Tags: php, apache, docker, ubuntu-14.04, docker-exec

I want login with docker through php.

I have tried with below command in php.

```
$content = system('sudo docker exec -it 8a3d7166d18d bash ;', $ret);
```

But it is giving below error:

```
the input device is not a TTY
```

It works perfectly through terminal in ubuntu. But not working that file in browser.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099116/error-the-input-device-is-not-a-tty, remove the option 't'.

Comment: Not working without ```t```.

Comment: Euh no my bad the "-it" and add "-d", But I don't understand why are you using "docker exec bash" with php script? We can do that but the you will get nothing because without/with "-it" "-t" "-i" you will only run bash in your container without OUTPOUT and/or TTY. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/#run-docker-exec-on-a-running-container