# Docker and git bash: the input device is not a TTY. If you are using mintty, try prefixing the command with 'winpty'

Tags: bash, git, docker, mingw, git-bash

I try to run the following Docker command in git bash shell.

`docker exec -it service /bin/bash`

but I get the following error

`the input device is not a TTY.  If you are using mintty, try prefixing the command with 'winpty'`

When I try to run the command with `winpty` as follows

`winpty docker exec -it service /bin/bash`

The git bash shell just prompts for the next command, but mess up with rendering the text on the screen. How do I properly attach interactive shell on the Docker container on git bash?

I can run the command in Docker Quickstart Terminal, but the problem is the terminal output history is very limited (old output is lost when new ouput is printed). Alternatively, how do I extend the output history size to unlimited scrolling on the Docker Quickstart Terminal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error "The input device is not a TTY"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099116/error-the-input-device-is-not-a-tty)

Answer (score 4):

try using:

```
winpty -Xallow-non-tty docker exec -it service /bin/bash
```

it worked for me.

Comment: `Error: unrecognized option: '-Xallow-non-tty'`

Answer (score 0):

another alternative (if using Docker w/ windows 10).

(1)
If Git is not already installed: install it.

(2)
from windows 10 search (i.e., lower lefthand corner: "Type here to search"),  type in "Git"

(3)
click the "Git CMD (Deprecated) App"

(4)
use the shell that is invoked.  It seems the "-it" switch is supported...

e.g.,

```
 docker exec -it db2 /bin/bash
```