# Docker keeps complaining about the input device is not TTY

Tags: windows, docker, command-line, git-bash

I'm using Windows-10 and using GitBash entering in the command

```sh
$ docker run -ti ubuntu:latest bash
```

And it gives me this error message
"the input device is not a TTY.  If you are using mintty, try prefixing the command with 'winpty'"

And so I placed in this command to switch to winpty
`$ winpty docker.exe run -it --rm ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash`
And it still doesn't work. I know my ports are running correctly, and I installed ubuntu correctly.

Comment: I'd also like to add that I'm fallowing a tutorial where the instructor is using git in macOS, I don't know if the command line is specific to the OS but I believe the commands he's using is universal.

Comment: You're conflating Git (a version control system) with a bash (a command line interpreter / "shell"). Git-bash is a *port* of bash to Windows; Git needs a POSIX-compatible shell, so the Windows version of Git comes with this port. It's not part *of* Git though. I've updated your tags but you might want to add more Windows tags.

Comment: Okay, so if I wanted to run that command using a windows OS, it would be better to just use Powershell or standard CommanLine ?

Comment: Maybe. Bash is nice for doing shell programming, but doesn't really "play well" with Windows in general. Some large parts of Git used to be bash scripts; the Git project folks have gradually been turning these into other languages so that they'll run fast on Windows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker and git bash: the input device is not a TTY. If you are using mintty, try prefixing the command with 'winpty'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51782815/docker-and-git-bash-the-input-device-is-not-a-tty-if-you-are-using-mintty-try)

Answer (score 2):

At windows 10 and git bash this works for me:

`winpty docker exec -it "CONTAINTER ID" sh`