# Docker container_linux.go:247. What is the error and why it crashes?

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I executed the command:

```
winpty docker run -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash
```

And received the following error:

> C:/Program Files/Docker/Docker/Resources/bin/docker.exe: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/bash.exe\": stat C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/bash.exe: no such file or directory".

**Answer for @Rup:**

[image]

**Answer for @akop:**

```
$ docker run -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash
the input device is not a TTY.  If you are using mintty, try prefixing the command with 'winpty'
```

Comment: Does "C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/bash.exe" exist?

Comment: @Rup yes. i answered above

Comment: Try running this command in powershell ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099116/error-the-input-device-is-not-a-tty  As @akop pointed out you are running bash inside the container.  You don't need bash on your local machine

Comment: @Yan yes. Are you right! My command running in windows powershell

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error "The input device is not a TTY"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099116/error-the-input-device-is-not-a-tty)

Answer (score 0):

`C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/bash.exe` does not exists on your host machine. (Note the `/usr/bin/` part). That is causing your exception.

But it's not important what your host machine has. You want Docker to execute the `/bin/bash` of the given image. I don't know what `winpty` is, but a quick web search shows that there many problems with interactive shells and winpty.

You can try it without winpty.

Maybe need winpty some quotes. Like this `winpty "docker run -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash"`

Comment: i answered above

Comment: And with quotes?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error in Linux and turn out to be permission issue.  The problem is gone after granting permission.

Comment: how to do it???