# kubectl exec fails with the error "Unable to use a TTY - input is not a terminal or the right kind of file"

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, kubectl

I am running a jenkins pipeline with the following command:

```
kubectl exec -it kafkacat-5f8fcfcc57-2txhc -- kafkacat -b cord-kafka -C -t BBSim-OLT-0-Events -o s@1585031458
```

which is running fine on the terminal of the machine the pipeline is running on, but on the actual pipeline I get the following error: "Unable to use a TTY - input is not a terminal or the right kind of file"

Any tips on how to go about resolving this?

Comment: Try to remove `-it` in the pipeline.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/43099210/596285 (these flags are a mirror of the docker flags)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

When the flags [`-it`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/) are used with `kubectl exec`, it enables the TTY interactive mode. Given the error that you mentioned, it seems that Jenkins doesn't allocate a TTY.

Since you are running the command in a Jenkins job, I would assume that your command is not necessarily interactive. A possible solution for the problem would be to simply remove the `-t` flag and try to execute the following instead:

```
kubectl exec -i kafkacat-5f8fcfcc57-2txhc -- kafkacat -b cord-kafka -C -t BBSim-OLT-0-Events -o s@1585031458
```

Answer (score 47):

**For windows git bash:**

```
alias kubectl='winpty kubectl'
$ kubectl exec -it <container>
```

Or just use `winpty` before the desired command.

Comment: this is the ANSWER! it works on my win10

Comment: This worked on Windows 10

Comment: Thanks! This worked on Windows 11 too.

Answer (score 31):

For Windows GitBash users, use **Powershell** and **NOT GitBash**

Comment: Is there any possibility to configure GitBash to act like Powershell does? Thank you.

Comment: See answer below for doing this with gitbash https://stackoverflow.com/a/68163722/131391

Answer (score 9):

Remove the `-t` option. That requests a TTY, which as you noted does not exist in Jenkins.

Comment: -i still fails, see here: kubectl exec --namespace default -i svc/jenkins -c jenkins -- /bin/cat /run/secrets/chart-admin-password && echo
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/cat": stat C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/cat: no such file or directory: unknown
command terminated with exit code 126

Answer (score 2):

Just a hint for anyone that gets stuck like I did with **kafkacat** suddenly returning no data after removing the `-t`.

Turns out if there's no `tty` then **kafkacat** defaults to `Producer` mode, I never used the `-C` flag because it's the default to be a Consumer, but in this case it's required.