# Getting syntax error using kubectl exec as Unable to use a TTY

Tags: bash, shell, kubectl, xargs

kubectl exec does not work with xargs. may be am missing right syntax.

I have like 10 nodes to pull the container info.. like run command as `cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` but my first command itself is failing.

```
kubectl get nodes -l nodeGroup=test -o wide | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -l1 -- sh -c 'kubectl exec -ti -n kube-system nginx-proxy-$1 sh' --
```

OR

```
kubectl get nodes -l nodeGroup=test -o wide | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -l1 -- sh -c 'kubectl exec -ti -n kube-system nginx-proxy-$1 /bin/bash' --
```

output:

```
Unable to use a TTY - input is not a terminal or the right kind of file
```

when i run the same individually, it works. any hint how to loop over it with xargs am using same terminal.  below works but above with xargs does not.

```
▶ kubectl exec -ti -n kube-system                nginx-proxy-node1 sh
#
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
... | xargs -l1 -- sh -c 'kubectl exec -ti -n kube-system nginx-proxy-$1 sh' --
```

Try this

```
... | xargs -I{} -- sh -c 'kubectl exec -ti -n kube-system nginx-proxy-{} sh' --
```

Comment: `Unable to use a TTY - input is not a terminal or the right kind of file` still the error

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60826194/kubectl-exec-fails-with-the-error-unable-to-use-a-tty-input-is-not-a-terminal