# The input device is not a TTY error in Jenkinsfile with docker commands

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, devops

trying to run the  `docker run -it --rm -v` command inside the Jenkinsfile which pops out with error message like the **input device is not a TTY**

any suggestion to get out of this stuff

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may want to omit `-it` (interactive) if you are not running from an interactive shell.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43099116/596285

Answer (score 0):

remove the t and run  "docker run -i --rm -v" instead.