# "Input device is not a TTY" error while running a docker through SSH

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, cypress

I have a server with Docker and Cypress.
Cypress is lauch by docker with the following command :

docker run -it -v $PWD:/var/www/html/test -w /var/www/html/test cypress/included:6.5.0

It's good, it works well :)

I try to call this setup by gitlab ci.
In gitlab Ci, I connect with SSH to my server and i lauch the command :
ssh  root@MY_IP "docker run -it -v $PWD:test -w /var/www/html/test cypress/included:6.5.0"

I have the following output :
the input device is not a TTY

I can't find a trick.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43099116/596285

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the interactive mode (`-it`):

`ssh root@MY_IP "docker run -v $PWD:test -w /var/www/html/test cypress/included:6.5.0"`