# Gitlab CI job failed: ERROR the input device is not a TTY

Tags: gitlab-ci

I've registered a GitLab Runner with shell executor installed on Ubuntu 18.04, and also set up a docker container with the command below

```
docker run -it --gpus '"device=0"' --net=host -v /home/autotest/Desktop/ai_platform:/app --name=ai_platform_system nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:20.10-py3 "bash"
```

Then I tried to execute the following command from the `gitlab-ci.yml` in Gitlab CI, but I got an error `"The input device is not a TTY"`.

```
docker attach ai_platform_system
```

Any clues for this issue except using `docker exec`? I know `docker exec` works in Gitlab CI environment but it will create a new session in the container which is not desirable for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43099210/4620822) (for Jenkins but the same problem) you need to remove the `-it` flag and the tty.

```
docker run -T --gpus '"device=0"' --net=host -v /home/autotest/Desktop/ai_platform:/app --name=ai_platform_system nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:20.10-py3 "bash"
```