# Docker interactive tty attach detach options real meaning?

Tags: docker, io, containers

I am running a container with `docker run --name cont -dt img`. As I understand this provides the container with a tty but will not attach stdout, stderr and stdin of my host terminal to the container which is also running in the background.

Now I thought that if I did `docker attach cont` (docker documentation says it attaches stdio to a running container, [attach](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/)) I would obtain the same effect (by running first `docker logs cont` to see the stdout before the prompt) as running `docker run --name cont -it img` (display stdout/sterr allocate a tty and connect the stdin to the container). However my host terminal attaches but just hangs and `ctrl+c` must be used to detach (`ctrl+p+q` will not work).

I'd like to understand why `attach` does not work like I intend it? I mean the true logic behind it and how you came to understand this if possible, I know that running `cont` with the option `-dit` and reattaching works. If anybody has tips or can point to some reading sources to understand this it would help a lot. Thanks!

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt update -y
COPY . /tmp
WORKDIR /tmp
CMD ["/tmp/app.sh"]
```

**app.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Enter your name: "
read name
echo "Hello ${name}!"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without `-i` you have not connected stdin to the container. You'll still see any formatted output that a tty is used for, but it's only stdout/stderr. And from your experimentation, the detach signal (`cont-P cont-Q`) needs that stdin to be connected to be processed. For more on the `-it` flags, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43099210/596285).

Comment: But `docker attach cont` *should* connect stdout/stderr/stdin from host to guest as it says in the documentation. That is what I do not understand.

Comment: @lucmobz it would attach stdin if it existed, but that doesn't exist to attach to when the container is created without the option.

Comment: Ok it makes sense, but the documentation about `docker attach` I found really confusing as it did not mention *attach if it exists*.

Comment: It still is confusing however that if I run `docker run --name cont -a stdin -it img` (which I assume is attach stdin but not stdout/sterr) I can type something that is not disaplayed (which makes sense because no stdout), can hit enter, from another terminal I see the container is stopped, but my terminall still hangs. If instead I detach with `ctrl+p+q` which works (as I used `-it`) and do `docker attach cont` now I can type and hit enter and it will display stdout (nonsense as I did not run the container with stdout in the beginning). Very puzzling. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @lucmobz perhaps a bug, the code is open source under moby/moby and docker/cli.