# Redirect host output to docker container

Tags: docker

I have a mysql container running in docker container, which is intentionally not accessible through any port, but is accessible to other docker container.

For example consider following mysql container

```
docker run --name test_db mysql
```

Now I want to run a dump file in that mysql that is present on my host machine.

```
cat mydumpfile.sql | docker exec -it test_db mysql --password=${MY_MYSQL_PASSWORD}
```

But I am getting following in response

```
the input device is not a TTY
```

How to pipe output from my host machine to docker container?

**Please notice one thing, it is not about error, by removing -it or -i, I don't get error, but I am not able to pipe output to docker container.**

The question is how to pipe any output from host to docker container.

[Error "The input device is not a TTY"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099116/error-the-input-device-is-not-a-tty) -- that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Use `-i` only, instead of `-it` on the exec command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a working example:

script.sql

```
CREATE DATABASE test;

use test;

create table test (
    id varchar(64) not null,
    name varchar(64) not null default ""
);
```

create container:

```
docker run --name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test -d mysql
```

run the sql script:

```
docker exec -i mysql mysql -uroot -ptest < script.sql
```

login and check the new database was created:

```
docker exec -ti mysql \
  mysql -uroot -ptest -e"show databases; use test; show tables; desc test;"
```

cleanup

```
docker container rm -f mysql
```