# Making a dynamic bash-command that pipelins git status-paths into a "dip"-command

Tags: bash, awk

I'm working on a project that uses [dip](https://github.com/bibendi/dip), where a code-sniffer has been implemented.

If I change two files and create a new file, so `git status --porcelain` gives me this:

```
 M path/to/my/file/comments.php
 M path/to/my/file/footer.php
 D path/to/my/file/some-deleted-file.php
?? path/to/my/file/test.php
```

Then I would like to run a one-liner, bash command that passes those three files (that is not deleted) into the command, like this:

```
dip sniff fix path/to/my/file/comments.php path/to/my/file/footer.php path/to/my/file/test.php
```

I'm looking for a bash one-liner bash-command that achieves.

Ideally, it would be relative paths (unlike what `git status --porcelain` returns), so I could run the magical command I'm looking for, from any subfolder of the project.

### Solution attempt 1: `git status | awk | tr | dip`

I think I'm close with this command here:

```
git status --porcelain | awk -F' ' '{ print $2 }' | tr '\n' ' ' | dip sniff fix
```

But that throws this error: `the input device is not a TTY`. It happens the second that `dip` tries to start up the docker container. Maybe there is a timing-issue... Hmm.

This command here: `git status --porcelain | awk -F' ' '{ print $2 }' | tr '\n' ' '` returns this:

```
path/to/my/file/comments.php path/to/my/file/footer.php path/to/my/file/test.php
```

I also tried adding a bunch of flags to the `dip`-command [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43099210/1766219) (`dip sniff fix -i` and `dip sniff fix -it`, etc.).

And besides, that doesn't account for deleted files.

### Update based on Ed Mortons comments

It's a good idea to get the `tr` out of it, to simplify.

So now I do this (but I still get an error, whenever it reaches the `dip`-command):

```
$ git status --porcelain | awk '{printf "%s%s", sep, $2; sep=OFS} END{print ""}' | dip sniff fix

# RESULT:
the input device is not a TTY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about `dip`, but this looks like it can't read from a pipeline. You can try the following:

```
dip sniff fix $(git status --porcelain | awk '{printf "%s%s", sep, $2; sep=OFS} END{print ""}')
```