# he input device is not a TTY. If you are using mintty, try prefixing the command with 'winpty'

Tags: docker, tty, mintty, winpty

If you are getting this kind of error then follow these instruction

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43099116/596285

Answer (score 0):

first, run this command in your git bash
`docker run --rm -v "/c/users/vipul rao/documents/github/wappalyzer:/opt/wappalyzer" -it wappalyzer/dev`

then, run this command
`echo "alias docker='winpty docker'" >> ~/.bashrc`

or, run this command `echo "alias docker='winpty docker'" >> ~/.bash_profile`
at last, `restart your computer`